# Getting a placeholder's value in Twig / Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a placeholder in my route -> {id}. How can I get it in Twig? app.request.query.all is an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{{ app.request.attributes }}`

If you `dump()` it you can see an array called "_route_params"

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[9]
protected 'parameters' => 
array (size=3)
  '_controller' => string 'Acme\SomeBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction' (length=58)
  '_route' => string 'index' (length=5)
  '_route_params' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

You can access this array by doing

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') }}
```

...and if you dump it, it looks like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'foo' => string '1' (length=1)
```

In your case it would be:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')['id'] }}
```